# CSSLint with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, csslint

I'm trying to use CSSLint with Jenkins Continious Integration using MSBuild.
I didn't found a plugin to install on Jenkins.

Does anyone knows how I can find a plugin that has the same functionality as CSSLint which can be installed with Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for [Violation plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Violations).
The latest versions of the Violations Plugin allow you to report output using:

- CSS Lint output `--format=lint-xml` and csslint violations configuration
  OR
- CSS Lint output `--format=checkstyle-xml` and checkstyle violations configuration
  [image]